# Click event not firing with dynamically create buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically created the buttons in a div. And binding the click and other events for the buttons. But the problem is, click event fired only one for first clicked button. It happens same for the other binding events. The sample code is

```
 $('#divButtons input[type=button]').each(function () {
     $(this).bind('mouseover', function (e) {
         // some work
     }).bind('mouseout', function (e) {
         // some work
     }).bind('click', function (e) {
         // some work
     });
 });
```

It works good when bind it on `document.ready()` But in my case buttons created far after DOM ready.

I also want to know why it behaves like this...?

Comment: *"buttons created far after DOM ready"* - then when is this code executed? before the elements exist or after they are added to the page?

Comment: ofcourse after elements exists...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using jQuery 1.7+ go for on(), and there's really no need for each() :

```
$(document).on({
    mouseover: function(e) {
            // some work
    },
    mouseout: function(e) {
           // some work
    },
    click: function(e) {
           // some work
    }
}, '#divButtons input[type=button]');
```

replace document with nearest non dynamic element for delegated event handler.

Comment: Yes, in fact, thousands of exact duplicates on this issue are posted on SO daily and they are always solved the same way, amazing!

Comment: @Esailija - Yeah, this question comes up in some form about fifty times every day. And there's always a bunch of answers that only use the regular on() method and not the delegated way. You would think it should be easy to just search this site or read the documentation on jQuery's site, allthough I realize it can be confusing for newcomers to jQuery.

Comment: @adeneo I also want to know why it behaves like this...?

Comment: @Talha - It behaves like this because javascripts event handlers can only be set on elements that actually exists when they are bound. By binding the event handler to an element that exists, like `document`, and listening for events that bubble up from lower elements, we "delegate" the event handler to a parent element, and it works even when the element is added dynamically later on.

Comment: @adeneo can we use live() of jquery? i used it and it works? wats the difference between these two?

Comment: live() is deprecated, mostly because it is inefficient and has some issues, so on() is preferred if using a version of jQuery above 1.7, but live() still works, for now.